# Problems with autolayout in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am having some hard time as usual getting the constraints correct. This is how my tableview works:

This is the default display. The height of the cell is 57.
[image]
When you click on a cell, i change the selected cells height to 90 so it displays this information:
[image]

My problem is to set the constraints so it looks exactly as it does in both images. What is the best solution to this?

Would it be easier if i made two views and placed them inside of my uitableview so the constraints will be set for the specific view instead of the cell's frame which is being changed on user click etc. I uploaded my project if anybody wants a better overview of what is going on:

https://ufile.io/u2y5p

Answer (score 0):

You can also put your information inside a `UIStackView` and make them invisible until you click on the cell, use the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to make the cell's height dynamic, so when you will make those information visible, reloading the UITableView will make your cell's height higher

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are displaying the data on TableView from an array of models. Keep a property in your model class named as "isExpanded" and set its value by default false.

Now, use below code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let dataModel = self.arrayOfModels[indexPath.row]
    return dataModel.isExpanded ? 100 : 50
}
```

On select a row:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let dataModel = self.arrayOfModels[indexPath.row]
    dataModel.isExpanded = true
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt, or need more clarification.

Comment: I am sorry but i think you misunderstood my question. I have already implemented the code for the cells to expand and vise versa. My problems were putting the constraints that works with the expansion.